# each_slice ruby with a skip the first x slices

Tags: ruby, loops, enumerable

I have a backup script, which I take all the objects in a directory, and then with each slice of 30,000 I back them up to S3. 
My questions is now that I have over 100,000 objects, I would like to skip to slice number 2 but I am unsure how to do that. 
So the beginning of the loop looks like -

```
directory.files.each_slice(30000) do |file_array|

directory.files.each_slice(30000).skip(1)
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each_slice` returns an enumerable which you can then call further enumerable methods on, so you could use `with_index` to do something like

```
directory.files.each_slice(30000).with_index { | file_array, i | 
    next if i == 2 
    upload file_array 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hypothetical `skip` method is called [`drop`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop):

```
directory.files.each_slice(30000).drop(1).each do |file_array|
```

Note that like *all* `Enumerable` methods, it is not type-preserving, it always returns an `Array`, even though you are calling it on an `Enumerator`. Since you only have about 4 slices at the moment, that's not going to be a problem, but if you had millions of slices, that would eat up your memory pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
directory.files.each_slice(30000).with_index do |files, idx| 
  next if idx == 0
  ...
end
```